# WPF with arbitrary, unknown databases - Client/Server or Desktop app?

Tags: wpf, wcf, client-server, wcf-data-services

My company is planning to turn an older Winforms application into a WPF/Silverlight Client/Server app.

The idea of having a small server app is to have a list of the accessible data bases combined with the user type that may access each of the databases, instead of having to manage databases in each client's admin control. Additionally, it would be great if the SQL request would be handled by the server which would then return the result.

The app is supposed to work on a arbitrary set of databases which will be "registered" with the server and users get a list of databases according to their authentication rights. They can then do practically everything on those databases what one can imagine. The system should be able to handle up to 2 million rows.

The databases are very different, there can be many of them, they can be MS Access, Oracle, SQL Server etc., so no way for me to specify them all before. On top of that, communication with a SQLite cache is needed. 
I already have everything I need for the SQL queries from the Winforms app.

I was thinking:

1) A simple WCF server specifying in a config file the available databases per user type.

2) Interface that specifies all necessary SQL queries that can be made to the server.

3) Client...

The idea is:
a client-server application, where the client uses WCF services to execute SQL queries (INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, etc.) on tables by invoking services methods.

The service should ideally be consumable for both the WPF and the Silverlight app.

Is that the way to go? Which exisiting technologies might I want to make use of regarding formats, communication, services etc.

If that is problematic, I would consider going back to a desktop app, but then how to ease the user type/database access problem for each client?

Comment: Do the databases all have identical schemas? Are they "mostly" similar? Or are they completely, entirely different?

Comment: I added some more information in my question. Basically, no way to find a common between databases as the app is a data modelling app that is not meant to work in a specific environment or on a specific task.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with ADO.NET and start with the DbProviderFactory class.  This will let you determine the proper database access based on information supplied by the provider using the Factory Design Pattern.  So instead of having to create a specialized objects for each database type and database, you can abstract that logic with the DbProviderFactory.

Here's a link that shows some examples:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that seems easy enough for the server side. How should I approach the communication and formats for request and responses from and to the client?

Comment: Is your client updating the databases or just reading values from them?  Will your client side cache ever need to send updates back to the server?

Comment: The original databases will be accessed readonly, data can be written to a new place though, again in all possible formats.